# Which is the lightest view?

Tags: android

In Android, Which is the light weight view ?
ex:- View, Textview, Edittext, etc....

In some case we need to use a view to fill the area without showing the view to the user.
At the same time the screen should load fast.

Comment: What is your final goal?

Comment: OpenGL ES in NDK usually!

Answer (score 7):

You can use Space.

android.widget.Space

Space is a lightweight View subclass that may be used to create gaps between components in general purpose layouts.

Answer (score 5):

If by "lightweight" you meant memory footprint, then there is none exists on Android, because each view have to derive from `View`, which itself is a massive object (well, not massive, it is about 8kB), so it's not that big.

But in terms of measure, layout and draw time the basic View performs well. You just have to set its visibility to `INVISIBLE`. And so it will be measured and put into the layout (contrary to `GONE` with which the view would not take up any space).

Unfortunately `ViewStub` is not meant to be used for this purpose. Its default visibility is `GONE`.

If you are really picky, then you can extend `View` and override methods like `draw()` (to do nothing, do not even call super), `dispatchDraw()`, `setVillNotDraw(true)`, etc. (Take `ViewStub` as a sample).

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [ViewStub](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewStub if it is sufficient or LinearLayout which may be somewhat light weight.