# Which is the cheapest view on Android?

Tags: android, performance

For some reason I need to set a dummy view / empty view.

So I'm wondering

**Which is the cheapest / lightweight footprint view on android**?

I suppose a simple `<View />` will be the simplest and cheapest for resources. But maybe for some reason it's a `<RelativeLayout >` or a `<LinearLayout >` or even there is some hidden class.

I have looking for info but nothing conclude.
Please, add some real documentation on that, because I already have my opinion, but that doesn't mean this is the cheapest view, just a supposition.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18769371/2649012

Comment: A ViewStub is an invisible, zero-sized

Comment: @KlingKlang that seems to clarify this, I didn't found that answer before, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kling Klang pointed, the `<View />` is the simplest View, there is another view named `<Space />` but seems a wrap about a View, just for a readable name on xml's

Seems there is no performance improve about painting other views like ConstraintLayout, LinearLayout, and so on...

Thank's for finding that answer, it clarifies this and I have learned about ! :D

To clarify the other answers: 
- ConstraintLayout has improve performance about CHILDS, not the view itself.
- ViewStub is an empty view, for late inflate, don't exist on view hierachy, so not working for a background.

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

The View class is the parent class of most of the Views in Android (Texture, Surface, and many others) so it will be the most "lightwise" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `View` but There isn't any noticeable performance difference between `View` or `RelativeLayout` if it doesn't have any child because layouting is the most expensive job `ViewGroup`s do

Answer (score 0):

A ViewStub is an invisible, zero-sized View that can be used to lazily inflate layout resources at runtime. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html

Answer (score -1):

If you talking about whole `Activity` background you'd better use `android:windowBackground` attribute in theme styles.

Something like this:

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

            <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/yourWindowBackgroundColor</item>
</style>
```

And don't forget to apply this theme to `Activity` or to whole app in manifest.

Comment: No, I'm asking a concrete question, about performance, no a solution about the background, indeed that don't work for me, for some reason don't apply to discuse because tha question is other.

Comment: windowBackground is best if talking about performance way to set background to whole activity. Because it will be set for the Activity root container without creation/inflation any additional views.

Answer (score -2):

**ConstraintLayout is faster.** 
This is because ConstraintLayout allows you to build complex layouts without having to nest View and ViewGroup elements. Not only that it gives very good performance compare to LinearLayout and RelativeLayout. [image]

This [blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html?m=1) explains it very effectively.

Comment: Thank's for your answer, but this is a benchmark of Traditional Layouts (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout....) VS ConstraintLayout, not View VS View, so, this don't answer the question. thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Sulfkain have you read the blog(link), it answers your question correctly.

Comment: Yes, i have readed it, and talks about Traditional Layouts VS ConstraintLayout. from that entry about that : Our performance comparison shows that *ConstraintLayout* performs about 40% better in the measure/layout phase than *RelativeLayout:* Im asking about the lightweight view, not the better viewgroup